# File Streams Wtih Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to use Axios to download files from a stream. I don't think it is a problem with the server because it works if i use the `http` package. This is the code i have:

```
export function downloadRequest (savePath, reqURL, currentFile, serverPath) {
  const file = fs.createWriteStream(savePath[0] + `/${currentFile}`)
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${storedIP}${reqURL}`,
    responseType: 'stream',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }).then(function (reponse) {
    reponse.data.pipe(file)
    hashCheck(currentFile, savePath, serverPath)
  })
```

however this returns these two errors: 
`the provided value 'stream' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.`
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: reponse.data.pipe is not a function`

I tried doing what is said in this post: [Type error this.httpClient.get(...).pipe is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429953/type-error-this-httpclient-get-pipe-is-not-a-function)

But that made a windows popup saying something like this:

```
windows script host 

Script: c:\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Invalid character
Code: 800A03F6
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error
```

I went into that js file and Line 1 is `#!/usr/bin/env node`

I also tried uninstalling webpack and reinstalling but that didn't help.

Note: I am using Axios with quasar if that matters.

Comment: "I need to use Axios to download files from a stream" — Why? The error message suggests Axios doesn't support streams, and you said you had a working solution with the http module.

Comment: Is this on the server, or are you using `electron` or something similar?

Comment: @Quentin well i guess i dont need to, I just like some of the feature that Axios has like: ``axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;``
And:  ``onDownloadProgress allows handling of progress events for downloads``
alos in the docs it says: 
``responseType indicates the type of data that the server will respond with options are: 'arraybuffer', 'document', 'json', 'text', 'stream'
``

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande im using electron and quasar but this isnt on the server. The server is just normal nodejs but is running on another pc

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using electron, you should set the adapter to `http` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`

```
axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');
```

If you're getting `response.data.pipe` is not a function it appears that you can only get `response.data` as a stream in the main thread:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1474#issuecomment-380594110

```
ipcRenderer.send("downloadRequest"); // when downloadRequest is called
```

Main thread

```
app.on("ready", async () => {

 // other electron setup

 ipcMain.on("downloadRequest", (event, arg) => {
   // axios download code here
 });
});
```

Comment: That got rid of the ``the provided value 'stream' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.`` But the ``response.data.pipe(file) is not a function`` is still there

Comment: Are you still using `responseType: 'stream'`? Because it should work. Show the exact stack trace.

Comment: yeah i still have the ``responseType: 'stream'``and Im confused, what you mean by a trace?

Comment: The error, the exact error you're getting. Copy & paste the stack trace (the error shown in the console, with the lines and so on)

Comment: ok gotcha, this is what that says: 
```
RESTrequests.js?d591:96 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.data.pipe is not a function
    at eval (RESTrequests.js?d591:97)
(anonymous) @ RESTrequests.js?d591:96
Promise.then (async)
downloadRequest @ RESTrequests.js?d591:88
downloadFn @ Table.vue?a2a3:177
click @ Table.vue?bc0c:48
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6911
```

Comment: It is weird. Is this happening during a test using jest or something?. `console.log(response.data)` and show the output. What version of `axios` do you have, because it should work.

Comment: ok so now im more confused. The error about ``stream`` not being a type is back. and the log of response.data is a bunch of diamonds and weird symbols.

Axios version is "0.18.1"
And im not sure what jest is. Sorry im new to this stuff

Comment: Put your whole code, how you're requiring accions, how you're setting the adapter, and where you're calling the function.

Comment: ok. im going to put it in a pastebin because it is pretty big

Comment: here is the link: https://pastebin.com/h4dBkV92 there is a lot of other garbage that i didnt include but i kept everything that had to do with axios.

Comment: axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http') should be at the top of the file, after you require axios.

Comment: that still didnt fix the issue. Should i try creating just a normal node js project and see if the problem is axios or quasar and electron?

Comment: Im confused on this, so in ``src-electron/electron-main.js`` i put the ipcMain part, and then in the Table.vue i call the send part?

Comment: Exactly, that's how you should do it.

Answer (score -1):

In electron version 9.0.4, no need of below line

```
axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');
```

In Renderers

```
ipcRenderer.send("download_file");
```

In your Main use below code

```
ipcMain.on("download_file", (event, args) => {
        var url = "YourFileUrl";
    
        // console.log(data)
    
        require("axios").get(url, { responseType: 'stream' })
          .then(res => {
            var fileName = res.headers['content-disposition'].split("=")[1].split("\"")[0];
           
            const writer = require('fs').createWriteStream("Location to save the file");
    
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
              res.data.pipe(writer);
              let error = null;
    
              writer.on('error', err => {
                error = err;
                writer.close();
                reject(err);
              });
    
              writer.on('close', () => {
                if (!error) {
                  resolve(true);
                }
                //no need to call the reject here, as it will have been called in the
                //'error' stream;
              });
            });
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          });    
      }
```

);

Reference :

[node.js axios download file and writeFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374755/node-js-axios-download-file-and-writefile)